# How can I convert images to pdf and Word document in uwp?

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to develop an app which converts images to `MS Word` document and `pdf` file in `uwp` using `C#`

Which libraries should I use? `uwp` doesn't support `itextsharp`

Comment: try: https://www.syncfusion.com/products/uwp

Comment: I think the only supported library is only Apitron.PDF.Kit for UWP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Which libraries should I use?

There is no such lib for now.

For MS Word document, especially the version after 2007, it uses [Open-XML-SDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK) and currently it doesn't support UWP platform.

For PDF, you can try to write the PDF file format yourself, here is a [blog](http://i1.blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2013/08/15/how-to-generate-pdf-on-windows-phone-in-vb-or-c.aspx) you can take a look. This could be a hard work. Or if you don't mind to show the "Print" UI, you can put all your images for example into one `Grid` and print it and call [ShowPrintUIAsync method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.printing.printmanager.showprintuiasync.aspx), in this UI, there is a button you can print to PDF file. For this method, you can refer to the official [Printing sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Printing).

My suggestion is that trying to deploy or use an available service online, let the service do this work, and when the work is done, you can simple download the stream and save into files.

Comment: thanks grace 
i have an idea if i use media.ocr and ocrengine to extract text from image and write it in textblock and than i iwill write that text in word file is it posible?

Comment: @FarhanMalik, you can have a try, but I think write text to file won't make it become a image?

Comment: so what can i do btw thanxx @Grace

Comment: @FarhanMalik, please refer to my answer: My suggestion is that trying to deploy or use an available service online, let the service do this work, and when the work is done, you can simple download the stream and save into files.

Comment: will you plz help me how to export text form textblock to word document in uwp ???

Comment: @FarhanMalik, as I said before, there is no directly way, and there is no Lib for now, you can just try to find some service on internet.

Comment: so how will i use services on internet actually requirement is without internet

Comment: @FarhanMalik, I just found a free one for you, if you have other questions, please ask a new question. http://www.onlineocr.net/service/ocrwebservice, You can have a try, I didn't try this.