# How to convert an image to a PDF and Word in UWP application

Tags: pdf, ms-word, uwp, image-conversion

My `Mainpage.cs`:

```
public class imagesPDF
{     
    public static void main(String arg[])throws Exception
    {                  
        Document document=new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream("YourPDFHere.pdf"));
        document.open();
        Image image = Image.getInstance ("yourImageHere.jpg");
        document.add(new Paragraph("Your Heading for the Image Goes Here"));
        document.add(image);               
        document.close();
    }
}
```

I tried, but I couldn't do that find a solution. I want to convert an image to a PDF and Word document file in a UWP (Universal Windows) application? How do I do that?

Comment: Share what have you done so far

Comment: i tried the code in java, but i want working on Universal windows application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert images to pdf and Word document in uwp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38118194/how-can-i-convert-images-to-pdf-and-word-document-in-uwp)

Comment: What lib should i add?

Comment: your question already answered [**HERE**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38141729/3367974)